# Strange PC-Lint errors with member templates

Tags: c++, templates, pc-lint

I am currently struggling with PC-Lint (version 9.00j and l), which gives me some errors and warnings for a piece of code. The code compiles well and runs as expected. Here is a simplified version of it:

```
#include <iostream>
#include <vector>

typedef unsigned char uint8_t;

class Test
{
  uint8_t          inputList[10];
  std::vector<int> resultList;

public:

  Test() : resultList()
  {
    for (uint8_t ii = 0; ii < 10; ++ii) 
      inputList[ii] = ii;
  }

  template<int list_size, typename ResultListType>
  void loadList(const uint8_t (& inputList)[list_size],
                ResultListType & resultList) const
  {
    for (uint8_t ii = 0; ii < list_size; ++ii) 
      resultList.push_back(inputList[ii]);
  }

  void run()
  {
    loadList(inputList, resultList);
  }

  void print()
  {
    std::vector<int>::iterator it;
    for (it = resultList.begin(); it != resultList.end(); ++it)
      std::cout << *it << std::endl;
  }
};

int main()
{
  Test t;
  t.run();
  t.print();
}
```

When running this in Gimpel's online demo, I get these errors and warnings:

```
    30      loadList(inputList, resultList);
diy.cpp  30  Error 1025:  No template matches invocation 'Test::loadList(unsigned char [10], std::vector<int>)', 1 candidates found, 1 matched the argument count
diy.cpp  30  Info 1703:  Function 'Test::loadList(const unsigned char (&)[V], <2>&) const' arbitrarily selected. Refer to Error 1025
diy.cpp  30  Error 1032:  Member 'loadList' cannot be called without object
diy.cpp  30  Error 1058:  While calling 'Test::loadList(const unsigned char (&)[V], <2>&) const': Initializing a non-const reference '<2>&' with a non-lvalue (a temporary object of type 'std::vector<int>')
diy.cpp  30  Warning 1514:  Creating temporary to copy 'std::vector<int>' to '<2>&' (context: arg. no. 2)
```

So basically, PC-Lint is trying to tell me that it will just find the right template parameters by chance and that only a temporary copy of the vector will be filled. But the code runs well, the resultList contains the data!

Can anyone tell me what is going on here? Is PC-Lint right and something is going wrong or is this just a PC-Lint bug?

Answer (score 0):

The problem is that `loadList` is marked to be `const`, and yet you pass a non-constant reference to the member variable `resultList` that you *modify*.

It's true that the `loadList` function doesn't modify `this` instance *directly* but since you still modify a member variable the function can't be constant.

Either create a temporary vector that you pass to the function, or make the function not `const`.

Comment: I get the same errors/warnings when leaving out that const. I added it because it was mentioned in the description of error [1058](http://gimpel-online.com/MsgRef.html#1058)

Comment: @craesh It does work fine if you explicitly specify the template arguments, as in `oadList<10, std::vector<int>>(inputList, resultList)`. I'd cautiously say it's a problem with template matching and overload resolution in PC-lint.

Comment: It even works if I just specify the first argument, the size. I remember having had a similar issue some time ago, it was solved by `//lint -fvl`. Variable length arrays are a GNU extension that are obscurely enabled in the default lint config...